# Rearranging Exponential Equation 7

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Rearrange:
$(3-3x)^y + x^y = 1$
For $x$ as a function of $y$.
I have been trying for a while and have been unable to do it, please help.

Comment: Can we use Equation $6$ for this (the one before Equation $7$)?

Comment: Yes, you can use Equation 6.

Comment: Don't refer to "equation 7" unless you cite and quote the text you are using.  "Equation 7" doesn't mean *anything* to anyone not using the book.  (I suspect Dietrich Burde was making a joke... I could be wrong though).

Comment: Is $y$ a natural number?

Comment: Y is a natural number.